# Fastest way to extract a crop from a JPEG file on demand?

Tags: php, imagemagick, jpeg, crop

Users on my website can click a portion of a photo to get a closeup of it.

I currently have a bit of JavaScript that fires off an AJAX call to a PHP script that uses ImageMagick to retrieve the relevant crop.

Could I be doing this better, outside of PHP?  Using ImageMagick directly somehow, or something else?

Currently the files reside on the same server as the main website, but due to space restraints I'm in the process of moving them to a separate server, so will need to make a call between the two somehow.

The photos vary in size, some are 1600x1200 and only 200KB, others are 24MP+ 20MB+ originals.

Comment: Better than force your server to do hard image proccessing let it to client side ( JS ). Check for canvas html5 + js crop : http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/10/30/resizing-cropping-images-canvas/

Comment: Sending a 20MB file to the client doesn't seem like a great user experience...

Comment: I'm not sure but if a user can click a portion of a photo it means that he got it by a http request. Thats means (as I think), user get picture, select crop options, server take that options and crop it loading the picture to process it. So, may be better to force client side crop and upload the finished crop instead your server doing it. As you prefer

Comment: The initial photo that they can see is a low-res bandwidth-friendly 1024px version, not the full file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using ImageMagick, you have two options:

1. Crop the image while loading it. What is then loaded initially is a *cropped* image.
2. Load the image, then crop it. What is initially loaded is the *complete* image.

The first method is more efficient and faster.

This method is to append the image area information ***to the input image(s)*** in square brackets (`[...]`) like this:

```
convert wizard:[130x150+80+80] -resize 200% wiz-head.png
```

This will crop a piece of `130x150` pixels with an offset of 80 pixels from the top left corner of the original, built-in `wizard:` image. Here are both images side by side, `wizard:` (left) and the cropped section, resized by 200%:

[image] 
[image]

If you wanted to crop a JPEG, you'd use something like:

```
   convert some.jpeg[330x250+180+280] -resize 300% output.png
```

Comment: Thanks.  And what's the best way to utilise this in a PHP script?  Should I be using http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php, or can I speed it up using direct commandline access to IM like your example?

Comment: @Codemonkey: Sorry -- *that* question I'm not competent to answer. If I were you, I would design + run a few benchmarks *with your environment and test images* and then decide.